# How to read from where it stopped in a loop?

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I do have text file having 500k data.

I am running a loop to store some info. something like..

```
$file = fopen("top-1-500000.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");  
while(!feof($file)) { //some function
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (name) VALUES ('$value')");
    }  fclose($file);
```

The issue is when the loop stopped in the middle then I need to delete data which already read from text file by reading mySQL database manually to prevent loop to read it again from first line from text file. this is a huge effort in terms of multiple files.

Comment: How do you read the file ? Line per Line or Char per Char ?

Comment: Why is the loop being stopped in the middle? Is someone manually terminating the script (like with Ctrl-C)?

Comment: best guess is you're running out of memory or execution time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative method of reading a large file is to use the MySQL [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) functionality.

Example:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'top-1-500000.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_name
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming by "stopped in the middle" you mean that the script is timing out. You should use `set_time_limit` to prevent your script from timing out (I'm assuming your server config allows you to do this).

Comment: script is terminated by externally ..as I am using API so there is limitations..I have set time limit by 100000

Answer (score 0):

if you use `file()` to read the file, you can just use a counter inside a for-loop counting the number of iterations, then when you need to go back to where the loop stopped, use that counter

```
$file_array = file("top-1-500000.txt");
for($i=0;$i<count($file_array);$i++)
{
    // ...code here...
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (name) VALUES ('$value')");
}
```

Also, this is assuming this isn't an absolutely massive file

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the file line by line, so

```
$line = fgets($handle);
```

will read [1024 chars by default](http://bg.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) (you can specify that)

There's a function called [fseek](http://bg.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) with which you can navigate the internal file pointer and read from that place on.
A possible solution is to keep in the database the number of read lines and when (if) the loop dies in the middle, you can have `$number_lines * 1024` to be the offset for `fseek()` 
and continue to read on.

Comment: That won't work, it doesn't read the full 1024 chars if there's a newline.